# Value of type '[UILabel]' has no member 'text' in quiz app

Tags: swift, text, uibutton, uilabel

Hi I am trying to do a quiz game I am getting an error about UILabel being a no member of text it makes sense because  choiceText is a type [string].

```
import Foundation

class Question {

    let questionText: String
    let choiceText: [String]
    let answer : Int

    init(text: String, choice: [String], correctAnswer: Int){

        questionText = text
        answer = correctAnswer
        choiceText = choice



    }
}


import Foundation

class QuestionBank{

    var list = [Question]()


    init() {
        let QuizItem = Question(text: "What is your name?", choice: 
        ["S","B","D","C"], correctAnswer: 0)

        list.append(QuizItem)
        list.append(Question(text: "What is your favourite cat?", choice: ["Bob","Marley","zed","fer"], correctAnswer: 2))
        list.append(Question(text: "What is your favourite cat?", choice: ["Bob","Marley","zed","fer"], correctAnswer: 0))

import UIKit

class QuizViewController: UIViewController {

    let allQuestions = QuestionBank()

    @IBOutlet weak var QuestionProgress: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var QuestionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ChoiceLabel: [UILabel]!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let firstQuestion = allQuestions.list[0]
        QuestionLabel.text = firstQuestion.questionText
        ChoiceLabel.text = firstQuestion.choiceText //Value of type 
       '[UILabel]' has no member 'text'
```

I first tried to do it as buttons then I just added labels on top of the question choices and tried to display the labels but it still didn't work.
If there are any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Comment: ChoiceLabel is of type Array<UILabel>

Comment: An array of `UILabel`s doesn't have a `text` member, its members do. Iterate through the array if you want to access them (with `forEach`, for example).

Comment: The error message is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

`ChoiceLabel`  declared here

```
 @IBOutlet var ChoiceLabel: [UILabel]!
```

is an array of labels , if it's a collection you have to index it

```
(0...ChoiceLabel.count-1).forEach { ChoiceLabel[$0].text = firstQuestion.choiceText[$0] }
```

Comment: ChoiceLabel[0].text = firstQuestion.choiceText I have tried that . Should this work instead: ChoiceLabel[0].text = firstQuestion.choiceText[0]

Comment: I have tried that before but it says type [string] cannot be signed to type string. Any suggestions

Comment: choiceText is also an array of strings

Comment: It's better to use first to fetch the first item from an array: `ChoiceLabel.first?.text = firstQuestion.choiceText.first ?? ""`

Comment: @DuncanC I agree